# Rollup plugin analyzer what bundle size limit does limitBytes value translate to?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bundle, rollup, rollupjs

I've added [rollup plugin analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-analyzer) to a ReactJS project.

Under the "CI usage example" section from the above link, there is a variable `const limitBytes = 1e6`

```
const limitBytes = 1e6

const onAnalysis = ({ bundleSize }) => {
  if (bundleSize < limitBytes) return
  console.log(`Bundle size exceeds ${limitBytes} bytes: ${bundleSize} bytes`)
  return process.exit(1)
}

rollup({
  entry: 'main.js',
  plugins: [analyze({ onAnalysis, skipFormatted: true })]
}).then(...)
```

I took a look through documentation, and may have missed something, though am not finding `limitBytes`.

Does anyone know what `1e6` would translate to in terms of bundle size limit, or how I would go about finding out?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can imagine this number as a 1 followed by 6 zeros.
Javascript makes no difference between `1e6`, `1000000` or `1_000_000`

In the example, a warning will be displayed if your bundle size equals or exceeds 1 mb.

```js
const numberInScientificNotation = 1e6
const numberWithUnderscores = 1_000_000

console.log(numberInScientificNotation)
console.log(numberWithUnderscores)
```